# C# adding buttons to custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, custom-controls

Maybe it is lame question but I am creating own control and I derived it from class UserControl and I draw some line and graphics and I want to ask if there is a way how I can add controls like buttons and textboxes and how can I do that. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the designer and toolbox?

Comment: I was looking for hard way and forget about this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a wonderful step-by-step walkthrough on how to author your own user control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207(v=VS.100).aspx

You can select the version of Visual Studio you are using at the top of the page. The link I posted is the VS2010 page.